# how to insert into a list if it contains a substring - WEB API

Tags: c#, .net, search, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to display the Product details using a list if it contains a specific searchString.

```
List<ProductsViewModel> ProductList = new List<ProductsViewModel>();
            using (var context = new Trainee1334Context())
            {
                ProductList = context.Products.Where(p => p.ProdcuctName.Contains("Book")).Select(p => new ProductsViewModel()).ToList();

            }
            return (ProductList);
```

it is returning null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to to fill out the values in the projection.

This is your problem.

```
Select(p => new ProductsViewModel())
```

Should be more like

```
Select(p => new ProductsViewModel()
          {
              Name = p.Name,
              SomethingElse = p.SomethingElse 
          }).
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your viewmodel. You don't need to create the ProductList upfront

```
IEnumerable<ProductsViewModel> productList;
using (var context = new Trainee1334Context())
{
     productList = context.Products.Where(p => p.ProdcuctName.Contains("Book"))
          .Select(p => new ProductsViewModel() 
          {
             Name = p.Name,
             Price = p.Price,
             // initialize all viewmodel properties
          });
}
return productList;
```